# Executing bash scripts using child_process under PM2 causes the process to restart once the script completes

Tags: node.js, child-process, pm2

I built a home-grown Netlify. It answers webhooks from Github and executes a bash script to deploy a cute React SPA.

It works great but when run under a PM2 process manager environment, it restarts once the child process closes/exits. I've tested many things - I've even built a test endpoint that feeds it fake data as repeatedly committing fake deploys got tiresome.

Here's some basic code:

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');

async function processDeploy(deploy) {
  console.log(`Processing commit: ${deploy.commit.id}...`);

  childProcess.execFile('./deploy.sh', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (!error) {
      // a function to report the result of the commit
      postDeploy(stdout, stderr, deploy.commit, { state: 'deployed' });
    } else {
      postDeploy('{}', error, deploy.commit, { state: 'error' });
    }
  });
}
```

There's a bunch of supporting functions that keep track of the queue and so on to serve a basic status frontend.

I've spent a long time picking through Node and PM2 logs only to find... Nothing. And I think it's partly due to my suspicion that there isn't actually an error - **PM2 executes the script, the script exits once completed, and PM2 decides that it's time to kill the process**.

The process then restarts as it's set to restart on kill/die.

**So, how does PM2 differ to `npm start` when running my Express-based app?** More importantly, how do I fix it...

In case it's relevant, this is my `ecosystem.config.js` for PM2:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'App',
      script: 'bin/www',
      exec_mode: 'fork',
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      ignore_watch: ['node_modules', '.log'],
      max_memory_restart: '4G',
    },
  ],
};
```

---

Update:

I've tried Node versions 10, 12, and 14.
I've switched away from `child_process.execFile` to `child_process.spawn`
I've investigated memory issues and scoured PM2's Github issues.

I am now confident that PM2 is catching the child process's event and confusing it with the parent process's.

Terminal output:

```sh
Deploy child process exited with code 0 and signal null // child process event listener for exit
Deploy child process closed with code 0 // child process event listener for close
Processing commit completed.
Queue empty.
Something is trying to kill me.  // parent process event listener for SIGINT
```